# Stack multiple columns in excel into two column set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have columns in C1:Ac1000 that are in two sets, for example like below

| A | header | B | header | C | header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Text 1 | no | Text 2 | sub | text 4 | no |
|  |  | Text 3 | no | text 5 | sub |
|  |  |  |  | text 6 | no |

Final Result: Stacked in two columns, with two empty rows after a header and one empty row after a sub entry. Each two set of columns may have variable number rows. Can this be accomplished via formula or VBA must be used? I only have the simple online Excel 365.

| A | header |
| --- | --- |
| Text 1 | no |
|  | skip |
|  | skip |
| B | header |
| text 2 | sub |
|  | skip |
| text 3 | no |
|  | skip |
|  | skip |
| C | header |
| text 4 | no |
| text 5 | sub |
|  | skip |
| text 6 | no |

I can get a formula to do the first two columns but then I don't know how to get the formula to jump columns within a row.

I have this in A5: =INDEX($C$1:$AC$1800,ROWS($A$1:A27)-27+ROW(A1),1)
this in B5: =INDEX($C$1:$AC$1800,COLUMNS($C$1:AC1)-27+ROW(A1),2)

Comment: This is not going to be possible with a formula, too much happening.  You will need to write vba to do this.

Comment: Why is it that you don't skip 2 rows for  **text 2** after **B | header** and **text 4** after **C | header**? Is that a mistake or is there an unstated rule? If that can be clarified, there is a solution.

Comment: Apologies, I created the table incorrectly - the header should have 2 skipped rows before it. Sounds like I need to VBA though, I would even be happy stacking without factoring in the spaces though (I can do via helper column) as my VBA knowledge is very poor. Assuming it has to loop once it finds the last line in a column and repeat.